# Get custom Value of Jquery into C# .net

Tags: c#, jquery, farbtastic

I'm using [farbtastic color picker](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/) in a .net project,
I need to get the selected color from the plugin in the C# page.
The right way to Get the value in jquery is:

```
$.farbtastic('#colorpicker').color
```

thats return the value I need.
the question is: How can I get this value in my C# page:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

css:

```
.txt{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.txt').val($.farbtastic('#colorpicker').color);
```

asp:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

C#:

```
color = txt.Text;
```

Comment: that a good direction, but what would happen when the user would change a color? does the .txt val would be automatic updated?

Comment: $('.ColorPickerContainer').click(function(){
     $('.txt').val($.farbtastic('#colorpicker').color);
});

Comment: I'm getting a EMPTY value in the textbox, although the the jquery function works fine, any idea?

Comment: probably a postback issue

Comment: ummmm
would you please send me your ASP and C# related code sections?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to submit the hex color value to your backing page: ASP.Net, MVC, WCF, or whatever, and convert that value to a System.Drawing.Color structure. You can use [Color.FromArgb(int, int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that conversion. If you need information on how to handle the submission, [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) is a good place to start.

Comment: I to submit the value from the cilent side to the server, That's what I can't do.